# django - custom field from CharField with default args

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I'm trying to use multiple custom fields in my project. For example `CurrencyField`.
I want to give it a default arguments like `verbose_name` - "mena" etc.

Django raises error:

```
kwargs['verbose_name'] = kwargs['verbose_name'] or 'Mena'
```

I guess it's because I sometimes use `verbose_name` as a positional argument. How can I make it "universal"?

```
class CurrencyChoices(models.TextChoices):
    EUR = 'EUR'
    CHF = 'CHF'
    CZK = 'CZK'
    DKK = 'DKK'
    GBP = 'GBP'
    HRK = 'HRK'
    HUF = 'HUF'
    PLN = 'PLN'
    RON = 'RON'
    SEK = 'SEK'
    USD = 'USD'

class CurrencyField(models.CharField):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['verbose_name'] = kwargs['verbose_name'] or 'Mena'
        kwargs['max_length'] = 5
        kwargs['choices'] = CurrencyChoices.choices
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you do not specify the `verbose_name` in the constructor, it will raise a `KeyError`, you can work with `.get(…)` instead, or perhaps even better: `.setdefault(…)`:

```
class CurrencyField(models.CharField):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('verbose_name', 'Mena')
        kwargs['max_length'] = 5
        kwargs['choices'] = CurrencyChoices.choices
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```